# AWS: Unable to insert values in Redshift table

Tags: python, sql, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-redshift

I am trying to insert values into a table within my redshift cluster, it is connected as I can read the table but I can't insert values on it. When I use `SELECT` statements it works fine but when I try to insert values from lambda function, it is aborted with no error or log info about why was it aborted.

The query part is like this:

```
conn = psycopg2.connect(dbname = 'dev',
    host =
    'redshift-cluster-summaries.c0xcgwtgz65l.us-east-2.redshift.amazonaws.com',
    port = '5439',
    user = '****',
    password = '****%')
cur = conn.cursor()
cur.execute("INSERT INTO public.summaries(topic,summary)
values('data', 'data_summary');")    
#print(cur.fetchone())
cur.close()
conn.close()
```

As I said, there is no log information about why was it aborted, neither it is giving me any kind of error. Actually, when I just use a Select statement, it works.

[image: Example of query loads]

Is there anyone who can guide me through what could be going on?

Comment: Questions - Does the user you using have insert rights to the table?  What does "aborted" mean if you are not seeing an error message?  Change doesn't take effect?  Are you committing the change?

Answer (score 2):

You forgot to do `conn.commit()`

```py
conn = psycopg2.connect(dbname = 'dev',
                        host = 'redshift-cluster-summaries.c0xcgwtgz65l.us-east-2.redshift.amazonaws.com',
                        port = '5439',
                        user = '****',
                        password = '****%')
cur = conn.cursor()

cur.execute("INSERT INTO public.summaries(topic,summary) values('data', 'data_summary');")    
cur.close()

conn.commit()
conn.close()
```

a bit improved way to run this

```py
from contextlib import contextmanager

@contextmanager
def cursor():
    with psycopg2.connect(dbname = 'dev',
                        host = 'redshift-cluster-summaries.c0xcgwtgz65l.us-east-2.redshift.amazonaws.com',
                        port = '5439',
                        user = '****',
                        password = '****%') as conn:
        try:
            yield conn.cursor()
        finally:
            try:
                conn.commit()
            except psycopg2.InterfaceError:
                pass

    
def run_insert(query):
    with cursor() as cur:
        cur.execute(query)    
        cur.close()


run_insert("INSERT INTO public.summaries(topic,summary) values('data', 'data_summary');")
```